# flutter inversed corner for containers

Tags: flutter, dart

how can I make two containers intersect in corners like that?

what I want to make is in the red rectangle
[image]

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this you have to use Custom Paint.
it is a little hard to do.
[Custome Paint](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7560981-drawing-custom-shapes-with-custompainter-in-flutter) This is a good explanation.

[Flutter Shapemaker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/) this will make your job very easy.